# LaTeX doesn't work in matplotlib (Python 2.7.13 | Anaconda (64-bit))

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, latex, anaconda

I have this very simple code and I am trying write in LaTeX

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Computer Modern']})
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)

plt.pcolor(np.arange(20).reshape(4,5))
cb = plt.colorbar(label=r'\textbf{a label}')
plt.show()
```

I get this error:

```
'latex' n�est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme ex�cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 197, in __draw_idle_agg
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 464, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1143, in draw
    renderer, self, dsu, self.suppressComposite)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 139, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2409, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, dsu)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 139, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1138, in draw
    renderer)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1078, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 967, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 353, in _get_layout
    ismath=False)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 230, in get_text_width_height_descent
    renderer=self)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 676, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 423, in make_dvi
    report))
RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
'lp'
Here is the full report generated by LaTeX:
```

**Translation:**

`'latex' n�est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme ex�cutable ou un fichier de commandes.` means `'latex' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program, or a batch file.`

How can I fix this error ?

My Python:

Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 19 2016, 13:29:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: You need to make sure that `latex` can be run from the command line from any point on the system, e.g. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dlug.png). Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, I use LaTeX almost everyday (Miktex + Texmaker). I didn't have this issue before but then I upgraded Anaconda and then I began to have this error.

Comment: Next step: [Try deleting your tex.cache folder](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#troubleshooting).

Comment: I did it and Miktex is in the PATH.

Comment: Apparently it can happen that although it is in the PATH seen by windows, it's not in the PATH seen by python. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265688/how-can-i-add-the-latex-on-python-path

Comment: I did it but it didn't work for me. Then, in the Anaconda Navigator I installed  miktex from the conda-forge channel, and miktex-portable, mixtec-selected, cg-latex from the clinicalgraphics channel. It worked after that but I don't know which one of these made it work. I also had multiple issues after that (the Anaconda Navigator was shut down) but then I uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda without installing the packages that I previously installed and it worked fine. It's magic!